# Trying to figure out where this warning is coming from regarding unique keys

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

I keep getting the warning: "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop in ShowcaseLayout

I've tried going through each area of my code where I use the map function and supply a key that is unique(some of the keys are uuid) yet I can't seem to get the error message to go away

```
generateDOM() {

    return _.map(this.state.layouts[this.state.currentBreakpoint], l => {

      if (this.state.feedList[l.i] !== undefined && this.state.feedList.length > 0){
      return (

        <div key={l.i} className={l.static ? "static" : ""}>

            <div className="jsmpeg" data-url={this.state.feedList[l.i].streamURL} uuid={this.state.feedList[l.i].uuid} >
        </div>    
        );
       } 
    });
  }
```

```
    ReactDOM.createPortal( (
      <Form.Group controlId="enableVal" >
          <Form.Control name="enablecamera" className="enableOptionsBox"  as="select" multiple>
        { this.state.options.map((item) => <option key={item.key} name={item.name} value={item.value} uuid={item.uuid}>{item.name}</option>) }



        </Form.Control>
    <Button variant="Success" className="btn btn-success" onClick={ () => {
          sendEnable();
    }} >
      Enable
    </Button>

    </Form.Group>
    ), document.getElementById('enableForm')) ];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance that you're still mapping duplicate ID's/UUID's to the iterated elements.

To guarantee that it's a unique value, you could return the index of the map and provide that to the element like this:

```
generateDOM() {
  return _.map(this.state.layouts[this.state.currentBreakpoint], (l, index) => {
    if (this.state.feedList[l.i] !== undefined && this.state.feedList.length > 0){
      return (
        <div key={index} className={l.static ? "static" : ""}>
            <div className="jsmpeg" data-url={this.state.feedList[l.i].streamURL} uuid={this.state.feedList[l.i].uuid} >
        </div>    
      );
     } 
  });
}
```

Comment: You should not use the index as the key, because that can cause issues, if the list is reordered.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning item.key add idx as a part of key
.map((item) =>

Hope below helps,
.map((item, idx) =>

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You should log all your list items and check, if there are duplicated keys. You should not use the index as a key, because that can cause errors, if you reorder the list. There is nothing wrong with this code, but probably with the feedList ids.